# Logistic regression - Sample period longer than outcome period

Tags: regression, logistic, logit, endogeneity

In a credit risk model, **the probability of defaulting 18 months in the future is estimated** as a function of a set of characteristics $x$. We index individuals with $i$ and periods with $t$.

An outcome variable $y^i_t$ is constructed so that:

$y^i_t = 1$ if $Default^i_{t+18m} = 1$

$y^i_t = 0$ if $Default^i_{t+18m} = 0$

Then the regression has the form: $logit(y^i_t) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x^i_t +...$

However, **due to very few observations data from 60 months is aggregated and the regression is ran on the aggregated sample**. My main concern is that in the new sample there will be observations for the same clients at period $t$ and $t+18$ so that:

$logit(y^i_t) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x^i_t +...$

$logit(y^i_{t+18}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x^i_{t+18} +...$

**Could this be a cause of endogeneity and other problems?**

For example, since $y^i_t = Default^i_{t+18}$ , If the default in any period depends on the characteristics for that period so that: $Default^i_{t+18} = f(x^i_{t+18})$ then we would be estimating

$f(x^i_{t+18}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x^i_t +...$

Furthermore, the default flag is very correlated across time, i.e. once an individual defaults at $t$ it will also be defaulted at $t+18$ so that:

if $Default^i_t = 1$ then $Default^i_{t+18m} = 1$

Any reference to relevant literature will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the default, if it happens, happens only once for an individual, at a particular time. This sounds like it would be better handled by a survival model than by a logistic model.

For a survival model, your outcome variable is a table with both an outcome indicator (as you have already produced) and an associated time for each individual, representing either the time of the default (for $y=1$) or the last time at which it was known that there was no default (for $y=0$). Survival models can take time-varying predictors into account and can even take advantage of data available for individuals for which the last data were taken before your 18-month time point. If 18 months is particularly important for you, you can then use a survival model to make predictions about outcome specifically at 18 months.

[This recent question and detailed answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/250863/28500) go into more discussion about the advantages of survival models over logistic models for this type of study. Statistical software packages, like the `survival` and `rms` packages in R, provide tools for doing survival analysis. Setting up the analysis for time-varying predictors needs some careful attention but is relatively straightforward.